# Copy cells from one a row in a column dependant on a value in the corresponding row in another column

Tags: excel

I have a mailing list on excel 2003 that I need to send out dependant on month of registration.

The list is huge and the data is frequently being edited, deleted and added.

So in column Q I have the month as a number January is 1 May 5 etc. I then have the email address in Column T.

So everytime the number 1 is present in column Q i need to copy the corressponding row in column T

I need to do this for each month.

Ideally i'd have 12 buttons with a Macro for each month attached.

I have no idea where to start with the macro any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for January (though based on Macro Recorder in Excel 2007):

```vb
Sub MacroJan()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:T").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
    Columns("T:T").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

but since really only using filter, copy and paste there seems no real need for a dozen macros.